# Can't figure out apex_item.checkbox2

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Since yesterday I am trying to figure out checkboxes in APEX, which should be simple, however I have failed to make even the simplest scenario work.

Here is what I did so you can tell me what I did wrong.

I have three tables:

```
create table semester(
  id number not null,
  name varchar2(30) not null,
  primary key(id)
);

create table subject(
  id number not null,
  name varchar2(30) not null,
  primary key(id)
);

create table semester_subject(
  id number not null,
  semester_id number not null,
  subject_id number not null,
  primary key(id),
  foreign key(semester_id) references semester(id),
  foreign key(subject_id) references subject(id),
  constraint semester_subject_uq unique(semester_id, subject_id)
);
```

I have created in apex a region with one select list with the following list of values:

```
select name d, id r
from semester
order by 1
```

and one report with the following query

```
select 
  apex_item.checkbox2(10, id, 'UNCHECKED') "id",
  subject "Subject'
from subject;
```

Also I have one button to submit the page.
What I want is to insert the ids of the subjects with the ticked checkboxes, in the semester_subject table, together with the id of the semester selected from the select list.

So I made this on submit process:

```
DECLARE
  v_subject_id subject.id%type;
  v_semester_id semester.id%type;
BEGIN
  v_semster_id := :PX_SEMESTER;
  FOR I in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F10.COUNT LOOP
    v_subject_id := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F10(i);
    insert into semester_subject(semester_id, subject_id)
      values(v_semester_id, v_subject_id); --I have a sequence and a trigger for the id
  END LOOP;
END;
```

On my VPS when I submit the page I get 404 The requested URL /apex/wwv_flow.accept was not found on this server. So I created a workspace on apex.oracle.com and there the page reloads and I get no error, but when I check the table, the data isn't inserted.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: check your query - `subject "Subject'` should be `subject "Subject"`

Comment: Apart from that, I've copied your submit process and it works as expected. I suspect there's something else missing from here that is causing the issue.

Comment: I agree with Jeffrey. Other than some typo I don't spot any obvious faults.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try to do it from scratch and hopefully make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out what I was doing wrong. The report from my sql query, rendered the id column as escaped html, instead of a checkbox by default. So I went to the report attributes and set the id column to display as simple checkbox, but this was what was messing the values. When I set the id column as standard column, everything works properly.

Comment: Yeah - that'll do it. Don't forget to accept your own answer!